# What reasons stop GitHub turning the 'tag' into a 'release'

Tags: windows, github, electron, nuget

I manage an electron application and have successfully been using [electron-squirrel-startup](https://github.com/mongodb-js/electron-squirrel-startup), [update.electronjs.org](https://github.com/electron/update.electronjs.org) and my [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds) for automatic updates. I have needed to update my application packing from [electron-installer-windows](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-installer-windows) to [electron-winstaller](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer).

Packaging into an installer has been great, and solved the issue I had with electron-installer-windows, but something is up with the auto-updates. I wish my app to update from **3.8.17** to **3.8.20**. The issue is probably in my configuration/deployment of a step in this chain, but I have reached the end of my debugging powers.

**In short:**

1. the call to find a new version continues to return the current version info ... because ...
2. GitHub does not turn the 'tag' into a 'release'

**Question:**
Is anyone else experiencing this?
Any thoughts on how to further debug?

**Details:**

**GitHub** I have a tagged release, with `.exe`, `.nupkg` and `RELEASES` files. It is marked as the latest release, is visible in "tags", but not actually visible in "releases". There is something about my files that is not triggering GitHub to *actually* set it as a "release".

Comparing nupgk info (.zip > unzip > dan_client.nuspec) with that from `electron-installer-windows`, it is identical format, and the sha1 check-sum has been verified using cmd: `certutil -hashfile <filename> sha1`
Same for the RELEASES file.

**main.js**
Standard code here. `update-electron-app` is called as expected.

```js
require('update-electron-app')({
    repo: `${owner}/${repo}`,
    logger: require('electron-log'),
    notifyUser: false
  })
```

**Squirrel-CheckForUpdate.log**
The call to `update.electron.js` sent as expected:

```
[09/11/21 22:58:57] info: Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --checkForUpdate https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17
[09/11/21 22:58:57] info: Program: Fetching update information, downloading from https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17
[09/11/21 22:58:57] info: CheckForUpdateImpl: Using existing staging user ID: a3883120-9694-5b86-8981-1b1015c25a13
[09/11/21 22:58:57] info: CheckForUpdateImpl: Downloading RELEASES file from https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17
[09/11/21 22:58:57] info: FileDownloader: Downloading url: https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17/RELEASES?id=dan_client&localVersion=3.8.17&arch=amd64
[09/11/21 22:58:58] info: Program: Finished Squirrel Updater
```

Testing the response by plugging the url into the browser:

`.../win32-x64/3.8.17`([link](https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17)) => `Status Code: 204 No Content`

`.../win32-x64/3.8.17/RELEASES?id=dan_client&localVersion=3.8.17&arch=amd64` ([link](https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/3.8.17/RELEASES?)) => `995ECDBC10F717E0704F5B774533EA2977C725C1 https://github.com/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/releases/download/v3.8.17/dan_client-3.8.17-full.nupkg 85360877`
i.e. this call is not picking up the latest build.

If I make the same call with an old version number, say 1.0.0, I get a nice response, but still referring to 3.8.17:

`.../win32-x64/1.0.0`([link](https://update.electronjs.org/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/win32-x64/1.0.0)) =>

```
{
  "name":"v3.8.17",
  "notes":"...",
  "url":"https://github.com/DentalAudioNotes/dan-client-builds/releases/download/v3.8.17/dan_client-setup-3.8.17-live.exe"
}
```